# Access to a function declared within an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I have a file called bbUI.js which contains this bit of JavaScript. Outside of that file, I'd like to be able to call "var x = new iScroll(...)", but I currently get the error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: iScroll".

```js
(function(){
var iScroll = function (el, options) {
        var that = this,
            doc = document,
            i;

        // More code
    };
})();
```

From what I can tell, iScroll is defined within an anonymous function, and is itself anonymous but assigned to the identifier iScroll. If that's accurate, should I be able to call "var x = new iScroll(...)" in other places in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `iScroll` function only exists within the scope of the anonymous function it's wrapped in.  To use it elsewhere, you need to make it global.

You can make it global by removing the function it's wrapped in, or by setting `window.iScroll = iScroll` inside the anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the anonymous function that wraps the code:

```
(function(){   // <- this
  ...
})();          // <- this
```

The anonymous function prevents that code from polluting the global variables, so `iScroll` is defined only within that anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this question depends on what do you really want to achieve and what the purpose of a self executing function. Anyway.. here `iScroll` is inside the self executing function and you have to make it available in the scope outside. I have given below two methods to do this.

Either just make it global by removing `var` keyword

```
(function(){
 iScroll = function (el, options) {
        var that = this,
            doc = document,
            i;

        this.show = function(){
           alert("hello world");
        }
    };

})();
```

or by adding a variable `iScroll` externally and returning the function.

```
var iScroll = (function(){
       return function (el, options) {
            var that = this,
                doc = document,
                i;

            this.show = function(){
               alert("hello world");
            }
        };
})();
```

to test

```
var iscroll = new iScroll();
iscroll.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be the following:

```
var iScroll = (function(){ 

     var iScroll = function (el, options) {
     };

     return iScroll; // <-- add this line

})();
```